# AWS - Registered target group are unhealthy and giving 502 Gateway error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pcfdev

Target group is showing unhealthy and I have looked at the security group, which looks fine to me.

Comment: Verify health check path and its return code. Are you expecting 200? or perhaps you are getting 302? (redirect)

Comment: Have you checked the Network ACLs too? And are you able to verify that the application itself is running? It might help if you can provide some details about your configuration in terms of subnets, security groups and NACLs, and what the target group is pointing at